# Can ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel return null?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

My question is can, [ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel-int-) return `null` ?

Is there any known cases where any of the driver implementation return `null` ? If so, how to achieve that case.

From documentation, it seems there is no such restriction. I want a second opinion regarding this.

**Update 1:**

In PostgreSQL, when I execute a simple query `select 1;`, the returned column name `?column?`.
My question is, are there any scenarios where column label can be `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDBC API doesn't explicitly forbid `null` as a value for `getColumnLabel` (or `getColumnName`), so it not impossible that there are JDBC implementations that return `null` for unnamed columns.

That said, I can't think of examples of the top of my head. As far as I'm aware, most databases generate a default label for unnamed columns.

Answer (score 0):

There cannot be a scenario where it can return null. Either it will return a value or an exception stating the no passed is more than available columns

Comment: Updated the question with more a clearer problem statement. @Bimlendu

Comment: Why do you think that? The API doesn't explicitly forbid it, and it is entirely possible that there are databases that will yield `null` as the column label or column name for unnamed columns.